# Android. ldpi device won't choose images from mdpi folder

Tags: android

I've only placed mdpi and hdpi images inside each folder, but when I run my app on an ldpi device, it won't pick the images from the mdpi folder, but from the hdpi folder. Why is that? Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

P.S. If I place images specifically for the ldpi device inside the ldpi folder, it uses those, but if i delete them, it uses the hdpi ones.

Help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the default behavior of Android. LDPI is basically half of HDPI and ANdroid basically picks images from HDPI, scales it to half the size and uses it.

Read the last note on this link

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: So by not placing ldpi images, and letting the OS rescale the hdpi ones, won't the images look strange? (I can't see on my app, cause i'm using fuzzy images as is :) )

Comment: Well usually the scale down is not that bad. Scale up causes major pains due to blurriness and pixelation. If you app doesn't have too many images, I'd recommend putting in separate images for ldpi. But if it is image heavy, then you could opt for the scaling down and see if it works.

Comment: Ok mate. It's just that a designer friend of mine will come in a couple of hours so we make the designs for my app. And i'm not sure at what dimensions i should tell him to do the images :) Well, i guess i'll just tell him to make them for mdpi and hdpi then.

Comment: Well this is usually a najor problem when u wanna support multiple devices. The ratio is such XHDPI:HDPI:MDPI:LDPI = 2:1.5:1:0.75. If you plan to support XHDPI, then your images will appear blurry in those devices. I suggest you give a thought about the xhdpi too. If you design for XHDPI and HDPI, you could just halve them for the other 2 ;) No blurry worry.

Comment: "No blurry worry." haha. It's catchy. Yes, after i wrote the comment i thought of doing just that. Ok, Shubhayu, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Android checks for the particular density.If the reference of the image is given than it checks for the availability of it and sets the image according to the density but if its not available than it will take the default image which resides in Hdpi folder which is the default behavior of Android.

Take an example of the default image of Android that is ic_launcher,if its present in a single folder,android is going to set it because it first find its availability than density.